# CSS Element Confusion

Tags: css

I'm creating a userstyle, through stylish and I only have a basic knowledge of css.

The webpage uses things like:

```
<em class=etc.>
<em style etc.>
```

I was wondering in css is there a way to only target the style form of em?

Comment: Before posting any que here on **Stackoverflow** try creating a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and also learn [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions , as it will help you as well as other SO users too.

Comment: Yes, you can just use the style attribute. For more http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is what you are looking for.
`em{
   text-align:left;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking but it *sounds* as though you wish to target `em` which have inline styles applied.

If so, you can do this:

```css
em[style] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<em class="myclass">Not targeted</em>
<em style="font-size:32px">targeted</em>
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this helped, please feel free to upvote &/or mark as the correct answer.

Comment: Have done so, I would've at the time of the comment but it wouldn't allow me for another 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

use
 as internal style as

```
  <style>
    .etc
    {
    font-size:14px;
    color:red;
    }
    </style>
<em class="etc">this is text</em>
```

or by inline style as

```
 <em style="color:red; font-size:14px">
```

Comment: It's 2015 and you are still suggesting in-line styling?

Comment: i am just impoving the code that is written do it by inline or internal or externally as you want

Comment: Maybe my previous comment was a bit harsh. Sorry for the constructive feedback.

Comment: i am just given the suggestion and to be apply or not it's user dependency